# Django filter more than one time mapping with ManyToMany

Tags: python, django

Suppose I have something like this in my models.py:

```
class A(models.Model):
  name = CharField(max_length=20)

class B(models.Model):
  a = models.ManyToManyField(A)
```

I want to get A which has more than one time mapped with B.

Answer (score 0):

We can annotate the `A` objects with the number of `B`s, and then we filter on that number, like:

```
from django.db.models import Count

A.objects.annotate(
    n_b=Count('b')
).filter(n_b__gt=1)
```

So all `A` objects are annotated with an attribute `.n_b` (the number of related `B`s), and then we filter such that this number `n_b` is greater than (`__gt`) one.

This then produces a query like:

```sql
SELECT a.*, COUNT(a_b.b_id) AS n_b
FROM a
LEFT OUTER JOIN a_b ON a_b.a_id = a.id
GROUP BY a.id
HAVING COUNT(a_b.b_id) > 1
```

Comment: @MOHAMEDAZARUDEEN: did you specify a `related_name` in your m2m? I managed to get the correct results locally.

Answer (score 0):

```
B.A.through.objects.filter(name="a") can you try this.
```